# Removing parts of data in whole column in table using postgresql

Tags: database, string, postgresql, data-manipulation, trim

In my data i have the backwards p symbols shown below. I have found a way to filter to only get this symbol. I Found out that this symbolizes represents a new line. I am trying to eliminate everything behind the symbol but can seem to do it. I have tried using the trim function but it does not trim anything or maybe i am using the syntax wrong?

```
select trim(trailing E'([\\n\\r]+)|([\\n\\r]+$)' from ri.dish_type), ri.* from restaurant_items ri 
where restaurant_id  = 12340 and ri.dish_type ~ E'([\\n\\r]+)|([\\n\\r]+$)'
```

where `ri.dish_type ~ E'([\\n\\r]+)|([\\n\\r]+$)'`
is how i filter the symbol.

[image]

How can i eliminate all the text after the symbol?

**Update**

```
select split_part(ri.dish_type, E'\n\r', 1) from restaurant_items ri 
where restaurant_id  = 12340 and ri.dish_type ~ E'([\\n\\r]+)|([\\n\\r]+$)'
```

using this gives me the same results

[image]

**Update2**

```
select split_part(ri.dish_type, E'\n', 1) from restaurant_items ri 
where restaurant_id  = 12340 and ri.dish_type ~ E'([\\n\\r]+)|([\\n\\r]+$)'
```

using this and removing the \r seems to get it to work.

thanks for the help! @Adrian Klaver

Comment: `select split_part(E'test\n\rmoretext', E'\n\r', 1); test` per [String functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html)

Comment: didint seem to work

Comment: Define "didint seem to work". Show input and output.

Comment: sorry i meant to say that im not too sure how i can implement that onto my code. the column i need to do it on is called "ri.dish_type" using E'([\\n\\r]+)|([\\n\\r]+$)' to find all those symbols.

Comment: `select split_part(ri.dish_type, E'\n\r', 1)`

Comment: using this code `select split_part(ri.dish_type, E'\n\r', 1) from restaurant_items ri 
where restaurant_id  = 12340 and ri.dish_type ~ E'([\\n\\r]+)|([\\n\\r]+$)'` gets me the same results

Comment: Add the information as update to question, not in the comments.  1) Does it work? 2) If not how does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it simple and do something like this:

```
select
       case
           when strpos(dish_type, chr(13)) > 0
               then left(dish_type, strpos(dish_type, chr(13))-1)
           else dish_type
       end as dish_type
from  restaurant_items
where restaurant_id  = 12340;
```